# Logistic regression model predicts only one outcome, producing a high specificity but very low sensitivity. How do I improve the model?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, predictive-models, sensitivity-specificity, dependent-variable

I'm designing a logistic regression model to predict hospital mortality.

Why? To identify 'adjusted' odds ratios for a variable of interest on mortality.

Methods: - set up using a training dataset (75% of total)

1. I have started with 19 variables (dataset 1684 observations).
2. Included all variables with p<0.2 from univariate analysis
3. Using stepwise selection (stepAIC function in MASS package (R))
4. Testing for confounding using interaction terms for variables in later models

When I run predictions on the test cohort (25%), I get the following model diagnostics:

- Sensitivity 12%
- Specificity 95%
- Accuracy 78%

Looking at the confusion matrix, the model is predicting the outcome to be the largest class -  leading to a high accuracy but very poor model overall.

**How can I improve the model?**

Possible solutions?

1. Go back to drawing board and find 'better' variables that may be predictive of mortality?
2. Balance the data in the training data set via up/down sampling?

Comment: How many events do you have? What do you mean by “the model is predicting the outcome to be the largest class”?

Answer (score 4):

I am almost certain that your logistic regression does not predict *only one outcome*, i.e., a probability of $\hat{p}_i=0$ or $\hat{p}_i=1$ for the target class for all instances $i$. Rather, it predicts some $\hat{p}_i\in[0,1]$, which you then compare to a threshold $\theta$, which you chose in some way. Possibly, you use $\theta=0.5$. You then label instance $i$ as "target class" or "non-target class" based on $\hat{p}_i$ and $\theta$. And it happens that $\hat{p}_i\geq\theta$ for all $i$ (or, equivalently, $\hat{p}_i\leq\theta$ for all $i$).

The solution to your conundrum is not to use a threshold and hard classification at all, but to deal directly with the probabilistic classification given by $\hat{p}$. More information can be found at [Reduce Classification Probability Threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352). I also recommend [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352), because every criticism leveled there at accuracy applies equally to precision, recall etc.

Comment: We really need a canonical thread for these questions. [old-man-yells-at-cloud.png]

Comment: The use of p-values to select variables is a no-no.

Comment: @frank is this to say that using a p value to test any point null hypothesis is a no-no? Because i seldom see the difference between variable selection and point null testing.

Comment: @JTH: testing *a single hypothesis* is fine. (Or multiple ones, with proper correction.) What is *not* fine is testing one coefficient, then removing it from the model if $p>0.05$ (or similar), and *then testing other coefficients*. Everything after that first test is invalid. Then again, I am not quite as stringently against stepwise model building as long as the goal is *prediction* as opposed to inference.